# Objects not getting added to the NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

```
Student.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Student : NSObject
@property NSInteger age;
@property NSString *name;
@end

Student.m

#import "Student.h"
@implementation Student
@end

StudentCount.h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Student.h"
NSMutable
@interface StudentCount : NSObject
@property NSMutableArray<Student *> *student;
-(void)addStu:(Student *)stud;
-(void)printStudents;
@end

StudentCount.m

#import "StudentCount.h"

@implementation StudentCount
-(void)addStu:(Student *)stud{
    [_student addObject:stud];
}
-(void)printStudents{
    for(Student *s in _student){
        NSLog(@"%li",s.age);
        NSLog(@"%@",s.name);
    }
}
@end

Main.m

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Student.h"
#import "StudentCount.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        Student *student1=[Student alloc];
        student1.age=10;
        student1.name=@"Nirmal";

        Student *student2=[Student alloc];
        student2.age=12;
        student2.name=@"Anand";

        StudentCount *stCount=[StudentCount alloc];
        [stCount addStu:student1];
          [stCount addStu:student2];

        [stCount printStudents];


    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program, I tried to add the student object to the `NSMutableArray` of the StudentCount class.
After that I tried to call the printStudents method of the `StudentCount` class.
The student objects are not added to the `NSMutableArray`.

Output of the above program:

> Program ended with exit code: 0

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Don't call an array containing student_s_ "student". Call it students. Lying in your code confuses you and everyone else.

Comment: And you are missing an init call for each Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate the `NSMutableArray * student`.

```
-(void)addStudent:(Student *)stud
{
    if (_student == nil) {
        _student = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_student addObject:stud];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @iAiator It worked.